Updating WooCommerce tax rates dynamically not reflecting in checkout page
I'm encountering an issue with WooCommerce where dynamically updating the tax rate doesn't reflect on the checkout page. Here's the situation and the code I'm currently using:
Scenario: I need to dynamically update the tax rate based on specific conditions.
Issue: Despite successfully updating the tax rate dynamically using the woocommerce_before_calculate_totals hook, the updated tax rate isn't reflected on the checkout page. The tax continues to be calculated based on the default rate, and not the updated rate.
Code: Here's the code snippet I'm currently using:
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'update_tax_rate_before_calculate_totals', 9999);

function update_tax_rate_before_calculate_totals($cart) {

if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
    return;
}

// Check if customer details are available
if (is_checkout() && !empty(WC()->customer->get_shipping_country())) {
    // Check if the tax rate has already been applied
    $tax_rate_applied = WC()->session->get('tax_rate_applied');

    // If the tax rate has already been applied, return
    if ($tax_rate_applied) {
        error_log("Tax rate already applied");
        return;
    }

    // Get the standard tax rate
    $standard_tax_rate = WC_Tax::get_rates_for_tax_class('standard');

    // Update the rate value dynamically, for example, set it to 10%
    $new_tax_rate = 10;

    // Log the original tax rate
    error_log('Original tax rate: ' . print_r($standard_tax_rate, true));

    // Loop through the tax rates and update the rate value
    foreach ($standard_tax_rate as $key => $rate) {
        // Update the rate value
        $standard_tax_rate[$key]->tax_rate = $new_tax_rate;
    }

    // Set the updated tax rate
    WC()->session->set('taxes', array($standard_tax_rate));

    // Set the flag to indicate that the tax rate has been applied
    WC()->session->set('tax_rate_applied', true);

    // Trigger a cart update to recalculate taxes
    WC()->cart->calculate_totals();

    // Log the updated tax rate
    error_log('Updated tax rate: ' . print_r($standard_tax_rate, true));
}
}

and here is the log output:
Original tax rate: Array
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tax_rate_id] => 1
            [tax_rate_country] => US
            [tax_rate_state] => 
            [tax_rate] => 0.0000
            [tax_rate_name] => Tax
            [tax_rate_priority] => 1
            [tax_rate_compound] => 0
            [tax_rate_shipping] => 1
            [tax_rate_order] => 0
            [tax_rate_class] => 
            [postcode_count] => 0
            [city_count] => 0
        )

)

Updated tax rate: Array
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tax_rate_id] => 1
            [tax_rate_country] => US
            [tax_rate_state] => 
            [tax_rate] => 10
            [tax_rate_name] => Tax
            [tax_rate_priority] => 1
            [tax_rate_compound] => 0
            [tax_rate_shipping] => 1
            [tax_rate_order] => 0
            [tax_rate_class] => 
            [postcode_count] => 0
            [city_count] => 0
        )

)

Can anyone help me to identify what i  might be doing wrong? Thanks.
